# Populate dropdownlist upon gridview editmode

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, gridview, ddl

I have a GridView that I populate from the code behind on Load. Upon entering edit mode I need one column to be a DropDownList populated with a field from another table.

Since all data in the GridView is correct in non-editing view (select view?) I'm thinking it has to do with the DataTextField or the DataValueField.

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvOFO" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-condensed text-center" DataKeyNames="OFOKey" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvOFO_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="gvOFO_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvOFO_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gvOFO_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvOFO_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvOFO_RowUpdating" OnSorting="gvOFO_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvOFO_PageIndexChanging">
    <columns>
        <templatefield><itemtemplate>column1label</itemtemplate></templatefield>
        <templatefield><itemtemplate>column2label</itemtemplate></templatefield>
        <templatefield>
            <itemtemplate>column3label</itemtemplate>
            <edititemtemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlStatus" DataTextField="OFOstatus" DataValueField="OFOstatus" CssClass="form-control" />
            </edititemtemplate>
        </templatefield>
    </columns>
</gridview>
```

Table1:

> OFOKey int identity (PK)
>
> Date DateTime
>
> ReceiptPointGroupKey int (FK to another table)
>
> OFOstatus varchar (FK to Table 2)

Table 2:

> DayTypeKey int identity (PK)
>
> DayTypeName varchar

Why this is I do not know, but the tables are linked by OFOstatus and DayTypeName (I've suggested linking by the int PK to the creator of the DB, but regardless of how they link I am having problems with populating the DDL)

Bind Method:

```
void BindGrid()
{
    using (EntityDB dc = new EntityDB())
    {
        var ds = (from ofo in dc.OFOs
                  //the join just overlays the name over the int FK of the OFO table
                  join zone in dc.ReceiptPointGroups on ofo.ReceiptPointGroupKey equals zone.ReceiptPointGroupKey
                  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
                  select new { ofo.OFOKey, ofo.Date, zone.ReceiptPointGroupName, ofo.OFOstatus }).ToList();
        gv.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as putting the logic to link the tables and populate the DropDown in the RowDataBound event

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with the value you are selecting:
Property ofo.OFOstatus of anonymous type.

Can you try to use named class instead of anonymous  type.